# fcgiwrap listening to a unix socket file: how to change file permissions

Tags: unix, file-permissions, sockets, fastcgi

I have a web server (nginx) and a CGI application (gitweb) that is ran with fcgiwrap to enable Fast CGI access to it. I want the Fast CGI protocol to take place over a unix socket file.

To start the fcgiwrap daemon, I run:

```
setuidgid git fcgiwrap -s "unix:$PWD/fastcgi.sock"
```

(this is a [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) daemon)

The problem is that my web server runs as the user `www-data` and not the user `git`. And `fcgiwrap` creates the socket `fastcgi.sock` with user `git`, group `git` and read only fort the non owner. Thus, nginc with the user `www-data` can't access the socket.

Apparently, fcgiwrap is not able to select permissions of unix socket files. And this is quite annoying. Moreover, if I manage to have the socket file exists before I run `fcgiwrap` (which is quite difficult given I did not find any shell command to create a socket file), it quits with the following error:

```
Failed to bind: Address already in use
```

The only solution I found is to start the server the following way:

```
rm -f fastcgi.sock # Ensure that the socket doesn't already exists
(sleep 5; chgrp www-data fastcgi.sock; chmod g+w fastcgi.sock) &
exec setuidgid git fcgiwrap -s "unix:$PWD/fastcgi.sock"
```

Which is far from the most elegant solution. Can you think of anything better ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fcgiwrap is now compatible with systemd socket activation. It should be possible to use systemd protocol separately on os without systemd.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to start fcgiwrap as a specific user and have it create the socket in a folder with the sticky bit set.  Stickybit ensures that all files created in this directory have a given group.

```
mkdir sdir
chgrp www-data sdir
chmod g+s sdir
exec setuidgid git fcgiwrap -s "unix:$PWD/sdir/fastcgi.sock"
```

You can symlink if you still want to see the original socket name

```
ln -s fastcgi.sock sdir/fastcgi.sock
```